# Get Text From list view item

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I am trying to get text of list view item. And I am making the header of Context menu is clicked text of item.

This is my view

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ListView 
                 android:id="@android:id/list"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />
            </LinearLayout>
```

And in oncreate i set the simple cursor adapter

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mysqliteadapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.thepatientrow,cursor,from,to);
            setListAdapter(mysqliteadapter);
```

In OnCreateContextMenu, I want to set the Heder title By Selected Item Text

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM,Menu.NONE,"Delete");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,CONTEXT_MENU_UPDATE,Menu.NONE,"Update");
    }
```

Please Tell your Valuable suggestions.

I Added Some images for easy your understand

[image: I have listview like below(All data shown from db only. No xml).]

And i want to show the context menu header, like below

[image: And i want to show the context menu header, like below]

Comment: Please make your question more apparent. I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
```

`View v` refers to the selected item on the list. In `R.layout.thepatientrow`, find the `id` of the TextView pertaining to the header (for example R.id.header_text_view) of your layout, then:

```
    menu.setHeaderTitle(((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.header_text_view)).getText().toString());
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. If i use "menu.setHeaderTitle(((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.header_text_view)).getText().toString())" it returns first list item value only.

Comment: try replacing 'v' with your_list_view.getSelectedView()

Comment: Please tell something more. I cant get you exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have to make the selected item shown as the title.
I have a custom listview with an imageview and 2 textview, so i just find the textview i want to show via its Id.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.listView1) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        String titulo = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_guia)).getText();
        menu.setHeaderTitle(titulo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    }
}
```